# jQuery .html() not executing embedded jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've scrolled through most of the questions in stack overflow and also Google and tried out a bunch of codes but still can't seem to get my code to work!

So what I'm trying to do is to get some text and scripts via Ajax and insert them onto a div, however, the inline jQuery doesn't seem to work. The text can be very long, so what I wanted to do was add a preview of the text, and when the user clicked a "See more" link, the jQuery toggled the longer text to display and hide the preview.

Here is my code that inserts text into the document;

JSON returned from Ajax

```js
if (resp['marker'].length > 0) {
     htmltext = '<h5>Markers<a class="pull-right" onclick="seeall(\'marker\')">See all</a></h5><hr>';
     for (var i = 0; i < resp['marker'].length; i++) {
          htmltext += '<p><a>'+resp['marker'][i]['title']+'<a class="label label-warning"> > Go to marker</a></a></p>';
          htmltext += '<p id="marker-prev'+i+'"><span>'+resp['marker'][i]['advertisement'].substring(0,50)+'</span><a onclick="$(\'#marker-all'+i+'\').toggle();$(\'#marker-prev'+i+'\').toggle()"> More </a></p>';
          htmltext += '<p style="display:none" id="marker-all'+i+'"><span>'+resp['marker'][i]['advertisement']+'</span><a onclick="$(\'#marker-all'+i+'\').toggle();$(\'#marker-prev'+i+'\').toggle()"> Less </a></p>';
          htmltext += '<p><span>'+resp['marker'][i]['catagory']+'</span></p>';
     }
     htmltext += '<hr>';
     $('#markerssr').show();
     $('#markerssr').html(htmltext);
}
```

funny thing is, several lines down, THIS code works;

JSON returned from Ajax call

```js
if (resp['corp'].length > 0) {
    htmltext = '<h5>Businesses<a class="pull-right" onclick="seeall(\'corp\')">See all</a></h5><hr>';
    for (var i = 0; i < resp['corp'].length; i++) {
        htmltext += '<p><a>'+resp['corp'][i]['name']+'</a><a class="label label-warning"> > Go to business</a></p>'
        htmltext += '<p id="corp-prev"><span>'+resp['corp'][i]['description'].substring(0,50)+'</span><a onclick="$(\'#corp-all\').toggle();$(\'#corp-prev\').toggle()"> More </a></p>';
        htmltext += '<p style="display:none" id="corp-all"><span>'+resp['corp'][i]['description']+'</span><a onclick="$(\'#corp-all\').toggle();$(\'#corp-prev\').toggle()"> Less </a></p>';
        htmltext += '<p><span>'+resp['corp'][i]['address']+'</span><span>'+resp['corp'][i]['email']+'</span></p> ';
   }   
   htmltext += '<hr>';
   $('#businessessr').show(); 
   $('#businessessr').html(htmltext); 
}
```

Sorry my code is horribly formatted, but I am on a deadline.

Comment: IDs must be unique. I see you are doing a loop with the same IDs.

Comment: Why are you adding inline event attributes at all? Wouldn't delegated event handlers created outside the loop get the same job done much more cleanly?

Comment: @Tomanow Im such an idiot! Thank you for pointing that out, I didn't realize I was at risk of creating multiple duplicate ID's. I edited my question above. Thing is it's still not working.

Comment: @nnnnnn I don't know how many results will be returned by the Ajax query and I need each result to have an event handler to click open the full text. I might be missing something very simple, if you know a better solution or better approach please let me know.

Comment: building so much HTML via string concatenation is a bad coding practice. But honestly, the easiest way to fix this code would be to add a wrapper element in your loop (e.g. a <div class="corp"></div>)  and use $(this) .closest('.corp') to keep from using IDs in the toggle() function

Comment: *"I need each result to have an event handler to click open the full text"* - No you don't. You can have a *delegated* event handler that you attach to a parent element that when a click occurs checks if the actual clicked element matches a particular class or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I see (but it probably is nothing new), is that there are different ID's called from within the inline jQuery.

`$(\'#marker-all\').toggle()` VS `$(\'#corp-prev\').toggle()`.

Also, are you sure there is *only* 1 #marker-all on the page? jQuery will stop searching after it has found the first ID.

When you run the following code in the browser console:

```
$('#marker-all').length
```

Does it output 1? Or 0?

Comment: @DutchKev I'm not sure I follow you. Different ID's from within the inline jQuery? Does jQuery break if we call different ID's from inline code?

I also ran the above code in the browser and it returned 0 (after I added the edits above).

Comment: Played around with it for a bit before it finally worked. Turns out that I was creating identical ID's for several different tags so javascript was breaking. Added the incremental value and works like a charm now. Thanks!!!!